# application won't start. Application has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android

Everytime I try to run my application it shows up a dialog saying application has stopped unexpectedly, both on phone and emulator. The program has no errors and i've tried cleaning my project and several solutions but non of them worked. the same problem occurs with several projects even the hello world project.

This is my main activity: MainActivity.java

```
 package com.noura.luba;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    TextView forgotPass, createAcc;
    Button loginButton;
    EditText userID, pass;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
             loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

             forgotPass= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordTextView);
             createAcc= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.createAccountTextView);
             loginButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
             userID=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userIDEditText);
             pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);

             createAcc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {

                     Intent intentCreateAcc = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateAccActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intentCreateAcc);

                 }
             });

           forgotPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intentForgotPass = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForgotPassActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intentForgotPass);
            }
             }); 

             loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                     String id=userID.getText().toString();

                     Intent intentLogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);

                     intentLogin.putExtra("User_ID", id);
                     startActivity(intentLogin);

                 }

             });


    }

    public void LogIn(View V)
    {

        final Dialog dialog =  new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dialog.setTitle("LUBA LogIn");

        final EditText userID=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.userIDEditText);
        final EditText pass=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);

        Button login = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);


        //Set On ClickListener
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String userName= userID.getText().toString();
                String password=pass.getText().toString();

                String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter.getSingleEntry(userName);

                if(password.equals(storedPassword))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
                else
                {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name and Password do not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }



    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();

    }


}
```

This is my xml page: activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context="com.noura.luba.MainActivity"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@string/blue" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/LUBAimageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userIDEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LUBAimageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="@string/user_edit_text"
        android:textColor="@string/yellow"
         >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userIDEditText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text="@string/password_edit_text"
        android:textColor="@string/yellow" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/login_button"
        android:textColor="@string/yellow"  />



     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/forgotPasswordTextView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LUBAimageView"
         android:layout_alignStart="@+id/LUBAimageView"
         android:layout_below="@+id/loginButton"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:autoLink="web"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:ems="8"
         android:onClick="forgotPassword"
         android:text="@string/forgot_password"
         android:textColor="@string/yellow" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/createAccountTextView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/forgotPasswordTextView"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/forgotPasswordTextView"
         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/LUBAimageView"
         android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/LUBAimageView"
         android:onClick="createAccount"
         android:text="@string/create_account"
         android:textColor="@string/yellow" />

     <include
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/forgotPasswordTextView"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignStart="@+id/forgotPasswordTextView"
         layout="@layout/noura" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the logcat

```
11-13 22:17:54.092: D/AndroidRuntime(340): Shutting down VM
11-13 22:17:54.092: W/dalvikvm(340): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.noura.luba/com.noura.luba.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at com.noura.luba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  ... 11 more
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  ... 21 more
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File #2E5894 from drawable resource ID #0x7f0a0027
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1899)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:286)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:173)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  ... 24 more
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: #2E5894
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:406)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
11-13 22:17:54.162: E/AndroidRuntime(340):  ... 29 more
11-13 22:22:54.263: I/Process(340): Sending signal. PID: 340 SIG: 9
```

I am new to android application development but i seriously tried every solution i could find. If anyone could help me find the solution that would be great.

**Edit**

this is the LoginDataBaseAdapter.java

```
package com.noura.luba;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter {

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "seniorLUBA.db";
       static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

       public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;

       public SQLiteDatabase db;
       private final Context context;

       private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

       public LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context)
       {

           context = _context;
           dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

       }

       public LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException
       {
           db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
           return this;
       }

       public void close()
       {
           db.close();
       }

       public SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
       {
           return db;
       }

       public void insertEntry(String userName, String password)
       {

           ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
           newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
           newValues.put("PASSWORD", password);

           db.insert("student", null, newValues);
           Toast.makeText(context,  "User Info Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }

       public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
       {

           String where="StdId=?";
           int numberOFEntriesDeleted = db.delete("student", where, new String[]{UserName});
           Toast.makeText(context, "Number of Entry Deleted Successfully : " +numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
       }

       public String getSingleEntry(String userName)
       {

           Cursor cursor=db.query("student", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
           if(cursor.getCount()<1)
               return "DOES NOT EXIST";
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("StdPass"));
           return password;
       }



public void updateEntry(String userName, String password)
{
    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();

    updatedValues.put("UserName", userName);
    updatedValues.put("Password", password);

    String where="UserName = ?";
    db.update("student", updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});
}
}
```

and this is the new logcat

```
11-14 02:03:10.618: I/Database(341): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "seniorLUBA": syntax error
11-14 02:03:10.629: E/Database(341): Failure 1 (near "seniorLUBA": syntax error) on 0x2bee98 when preparing 'seniorLUBA.db'.
11-14 02:03:10.668: D/AndroidRuntime(341): Shutting down VM
11-14 02:03:10.668: W/dalvikvm(341): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.noura.luba/com.noura.luba.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "seniorLUBA": syntax error: seniorLUBA.db
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "seniorLUBA": syntax error: seniorLUBA.db
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.noura.luba.DataBaseHelper.onCreate(DataBaseHelper.java:18)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:126)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.noura.luba.LoginDataBaseAdapter.open(LoginDataBaseAdapter.java:32)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.noura.luba.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-14 02:03:10.698: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is a resource not found exception in your layout xml file.

1. Check if all the dimen values are available.
2. Check if all the string declarations are correct.
3. Check if the noura layout is available correctly.

Comment: i checked all the mentioned above and the same error persists

Comment: The database name is just the filename on disk, it can be anything, something.db is fine.

Comment: @prem i just tried it and the same error occured in the logcat and the application didn't start as well. should i keep it "seniorLUBA" or "seniorLUBA.db" ?

Comment: @Noura it should be named as seniorLUBA only

Comment: @Noura, if the issue is resolved, can you mark it as answer. If you still face issues, paste the logcat details.

Comment: @prem the solution was a combination of your solution and velval's on this link :(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921073/android-application-wont-start/26921232#26921232)
the first activity openned but now the problem occurs when i try to go to other activities. i'll review the logcat and if i don't find the problem i'll post another question. Thank you prem

Answer (score 0):

If you start at the bottom of the stack trace you have a `FileNotFoundException` for resource `2E5894`.

As it looks like the only part of your code/layout that is referencing a drawable is the single `ImageView` and it's using the launcher icon I would start off by cleaning and rebuilding your project to make sure something weird hasn't happened. Eclipse especially has a habit of screwing up the resources at times.

If this doesn't work then you should be able to look in the generated `R` class and figure out which the offending resource is and try and work out why the device thinks it's missing.

**Edit**

Your comment hinted at an issue which could be the cause.

Colour resources should be declared as `color` tags not strings:

```
<resources>
    <color name="my_color">#ffffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Then when you use them in your views:

```
<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/my_color" />
```

Comment: i've tried cleaning up the project and rebuilding my project but the same result happens.
and the resource 2e5894 is a color and it references
 <string name="blue">#2E5894</string>
which actually works and gives me the color i want. I checked  R.java and i found blue in it.

Comment: i noticed this message in my logcat could you see it please and i'll add the class in which the database mentioned is present

11-14 02:03:10.618: I/Database(341): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "seniorLUBA": syntax error
11-14 02:03:10.629: E/Database(341): Failure 1 (near "seniorLUBA": syntax error) on 0x2bee98 when preparing 'seniorLUBA.db'.

Comment: I think this should probably be a separate question.